# Compass gem install issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have difficulties understanding why the compass gem cannot be installed, this happend when I unistalled compass and breakpoint from my gem list for number of reasons...

This is what I input into the terminal:

```
gem install compass
```

This is the ERROR I received:

> ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
> SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.ne…)

Comment: can you show your `Gemfile` source

Comment: https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/gems/compass-0.12.2.gem

Comment: I'm using mac, rvm is built in I belive.

Comment: rvm is not built in but you do need to upgrade your ssl certificates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your rvm ssl certificates are up to date.

Check their status

```
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs status all
```

Update them!

```
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
```

Comment: How do I repair my SSL certificates on Windows?